# Mysterious error that happens when Lightning Web Security is turned on: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'copy')

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-web-security

Recently I wanted to release a new patch version of my package and I decided to check something on the testing trial production.

To my great surprize, there was some error which I didn't remember in the released version of my package and I didn't expect.

The error was saying:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'copy')
```

[image: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'copy')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that utility component doesn't support reference through `this` in `Lightning Web Security` mode while it allows it when `Lightning Web Security` is disabled.

When you have a component `Utils` with the following code

```
export function x1(source){
    return source && source.length;
}

export function x2(source) {
    return this.x1(source) + 1;
}
```

and another component Main

```
import {x2} from 'c/utils';

export default class Main extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        alert(x2([]));
    }
}
```

and you open component `Main` you will receive error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x1') in `Lightning Web Security` mode and no error when `Lightning Web Security` is disabled.

To fix this problem, you need to remove `this` reference from the utility component

```
export function x1(source){
    return source && source.length;
}

export function x2(source) {
    return x1(source) + 1;
}
```